# Automated way to run jmeter tests

Tags: jmeter

I have a bunch of jmeters that I would like to run in an automated way. 
Are there any available solutions for this?
Also is it possible to invoke jmeter tests in a particular location from java ? I would happily write a web app for running them from there.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can be invoked in multiple ways:

1. [Command-line mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) (like from shell script)
2. [Apache Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
3. [Apache Maven Plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)
4. [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)
5. Execution from Java code via [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for extended information on above and more. It also contains some code snippets on existing .jmx scripts execution and even creating new test using only API.